# How can I open current file with Chrome in Macvim

Tags: google-chrome, macvim

I used to put `!open -a Firefox.app %` to open current file with Firefox, But I failed to make it with Chrome.

**I got my answer**:
`!open -a Google\ Chrome %`

Comment: You should submit your answer as an answer so the question is marked as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
!open -a "Google Chrome" %
```